# Does CSS have a way to automatically set the column amount in a table?

Tags: html, css

Does CSS have a way to automatically set the amount of (fixed-width) columns in a table so that they fill the width of the div element they're in?

Like, if you have a narrow screen, the table layout may be like so:

```
. . .
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

But if you make it slightly wider, the table layout becomes this:

```
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
```

The usage case for this is for an image gallery, though if there's a simpler and easier way to do it than by using tables, I'm all ears.

PS: I am trying to keep the amount of javascript/jquery stuff to a minimum, so I would prefer solutions that don't use it.

Comment: An image gallery is not tabular data so you shouldn't use a table for it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster that's a very narrow point of view.  If it is just a list of images (where 1 image goes in each cell), then you would be correct.  But if the image is presented with other information it relates to (who was the artist, when was it created, who owns it, what media is it, etc.), then an image gallery absolutely qualifies as tabular data (where each row = 1 image + associated info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with a `<table>`, but you could just use elements like this:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  ...
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#gallery>div {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
}
```

They will be treated like text, and wrap accordingly. Since they are the same size, the result is a grid. Additionally, this means you don't have to have a divisible number. If you have a prime number of elements, for example, it would be impossible to make a proper table out of them. Here, though, it gets taken care of for you, like the words at the end of this sentence are at the start of the last line.

Comment: Nugget of trivia: it's called a composite number ;)

Comment: A list might be a better choice than a bunch of divs.

Comment: Lists wouldn't work for what I was doing.  I wanted to fill a row horizontally before going down to the next row.  A list would just have one item per row, which isn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

No, but here's an example of a responsive photo grid:

**Seamless Responsive Photo Grid**

http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/